# Cannot import JFrame or Dimension

Tags: java, swing, import, compiler-errors, jframe

I already have the system library in my package and have tried resetting the metadata. What else can I do?

Errors with comments stating what errors they are.

```
package JFrameTest;

import java.awt.Dimension; //The package java.awt is not accessible
import javax.swing.JFrame; //The type javax.swing.JFrame is not accessible

public class Empty extends JFrame { //JFrame cannot be resolved to a type

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new Main().setVisible(true);  // Main cannot be resolved to a type
}
```

Comment: First a closing `}` is missing, `new Empty()` i.o. `new Main()`. And package/folder names are normally in small letters. And they must match. Use an IDE to prevent path troubles.

Comment: Fixed the last two (3) errors, and there are no errors, but that is on a different computer

Answer (score -1):

JavaFX was deleted from JDK, so you need to download JavaFX from [here](https://openjfx.io/), [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) or use [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/install-javafx-sdk-1-2-139156.html) guide. If you use maven just add the dependencies.

Comment: This is **swing**, not JavaFX. ;)